# Create json from xcom airflow task instance data

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have two tasks in the airflow dag. The first task hits the POST URL and the result of it becomes the param of second task. I am able to hit the first URL and send it to another task. The problem is, I am not able to create the correct json out of second one.

```
def create_dag(dag_id,
               schedule,
               default_args):
    def task1(**kwargs):
        res = requests.post('some url')
        return res

    def task2(**kwargs):
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        v1 = ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='taks1')
        for rec in v1:
            decode = rec.decode("utf-8")
            logger.error(decode)
```

The first task returns the json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 36,
            "idPercent": 12.67605633802817,
            "idPerson": [
                "Washburn"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "idPercent": 13.028169014084508,
            "idPerson": [
                "Nicole"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the rec.decode("utf-8") print me the same. I start getting error if i do json.loads on rec.decode("utf-8"). I want to create the correct json and then for each array value of the data i want to send a POST request.

I want something like:

```
for rec in v1['data']:
     requests.post(url, rec)
```

But i am not able to create the json and extract the data from it.

Comment: Have you tried to return the JSON dump of the res from the first operator and JSON load from the second task? Basically try sending serialized objects through XCOM.

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow, xcom's are passed as strings, in your case `v1` will be a string even because it was loaded from an xcom object. One way to get around this is to use the `ast` module which converts a string value to it's "correct" type. A word of caution, sometimes it struggles to interpret the correct type due to punctuation marks or similar.

```
import ast

v1 = ast.literal_eval(ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='taks1'))
```

Comment: please add some context explaining your answer so we can learn; it otherwise will be down-voted and removed due a lack of it.

Comment: It didn't work for my json string. It says malformed string even though the json is correct.

Comment: @Nikita As mentioned in my answer `ast.literal_eval()` sometimes struggles to correctly convert a string to a JSON due to certain characters. My advice is to examine your string for characters like /, \, :, ' or # and see if you can `replace()` these characters prior to calling `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: `import json` and then `json.loads(ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='taks1'))`